# which method is better to absolute position element in relative div or to use margin property?

Tags: html, css

I have a div container and I want to know what is the best method to position inner elements inside it.

For example :

```
 <div id="container">
      <div id="name">
            Name 
      </div>
 </div>
```

One way of achieving this is to give ny inner elements absolute position with top,left,right and bottom.

like this :

```
 #container
 {
        width: 331px;
        height: 561px;
        float :left;
        margin-left : 20px;
        margin-top : 10px !important;
        border:1px solid red;
        position: relative;
 }



#name
{
        font-size: x-large;
        top: 77px;
        left: 10px;
        position:absolute;
        width:331px;

}
```

Or using margin-left and margin-top properties

like this :

```
#name
{
       font-size: x-large;
       margin-left: 8px;
       margin-top: 13px;
       width:331px;

}
```

What is the difference between these two methods and which one is better ?

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Your #name div is the same width as your #container.

Comment: @Robert Yes that is my design

Comment: So this is what you want to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/sCzfF/ To have the name outside the div too? I'm not saying it looks bad, just making sure that it's what you want :]

Comment: You're going to need to provide us with some more detail on what the end result should be, even if it's just a quick screenshot mock-up, in order to advise you which technique is best. Also, why no mention of internal padding on the parent?

Comment: @seemly I forgot to mention the padding. So in this case we can have another option to position the elements. The result in both cases is the same, what I am trying to know which scenario is the best. Thanks.

Comment: @Mohammadjouhari so is the output in my fiddle how you want it to be or not? Cause if you used padding it will be ofcourse different.

Comment: @Ms.Nobody Actually Danield explained very well. I just wanted to know what is the difference between this way <a http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/GmNDD/1/ (position absolute)  and this way http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/GmNDD/ and it seems as  Danield  said absolute postiotn will be taken out of the flow at the time when other elements are being replaced, that is why in the first case the address starts at the top of the container directly. While in the other case it starts after the name div.

Comment: Actually I was asking you a question and you are still not answering it.. btw if he answered your question, the best way how to show it is to accept it :)

Comment: @Ms.Nobody I am really sorry I did not recognize your link in the first time. Actually after Danield answer, because he formatted the link, I  just found out that you have posted the same link. Again I am really sorry and I did not mean to ignore your effort. Actually yes this what I am achieving. But I was able to achive the same result using margin-left and margin-top property and I was asking which method is better and how they differ. I hope it is clear to you now. Thanks for help and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between using `absolute` positioning vs `margin` is that

With absolute positioning:

> An element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and
>   thus takes up no space when placing other elements.([mozilla](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning))

So if you have other elements after #name they will start at the same point where name does. (**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/GmNDD/1/)**)
On the other hand, if you use margin, further elements will continue where #name left off. (**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/GmNDD/)**)

As far as which is better, that's your decision, whichever suits your needs better.